# Open a file in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, io

I'm trying to read all the files in a folder. If the name is `index.html`, nothing happens. It's not even opening the file in the browser.

This is the code I use .

```
foreach (System.IO.FileInfo thefile in fiArr)
{
    if (thefile.Name == "index.html")
    {
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path + thefile.Name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);   
    }
}
```

Comment: What browser are you talking about? Are you getting any errors? Exceptions?

Comment: I mean Google Chrome for example, because there are index.html from websites

Comment: I got no exception. It's just not doing anything .

Comment: The code you have posted won't do anything. You are just creating a new filestream. What do you want to happen?

Comment: I still don't understand what browsers have got to do with it? Do you actually have a file with the name `index.html` in `fiArr`?

Comment: I just want to open the index.html in a web browser

Comment: 1. Do you have an `index.html`? 2. Why are you opening a `FileStream`? 3. What browser are you talking about - on the machine running the code? A client? Somewhere else?

Comment: you need to get your facts straight before posting the question - if you don't know enough about the technology then again, post what you know and what you want to achieve, what is the 'specification' of the problem. That's the least you should do.

Comment: 1. You can directly access html pages, there is no need to use FileStream 2. You can write the contents of html file to the output stream. You can edit your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that your code this is create a FileStream pointing to this file. So you could read the file and fetch its contents in memory. But you cannot expect it to open in any browser. You could use the Process.Start method to open the file using the default program that is associated with this file type:

```
foreach (System.IO.FileInfo thefile in fiArr)
{
    if (thefile.Name == "index.html")
    {
        Process.Start(thefile.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Emged - Your question is tagged asp.net. Be aware that calling Process.Start will only open a browser on the host/server machine. This may be fine whilst you are developing but once deployed you will be opening a broswer on a server somewhere that maybe nobody will ever see.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is putting the contents of the file into a `FileStream` so you can use it in your code.  You'll need to do something with that `FileStream` next.

If you wanted the file opened using the default application (i.e. appearing in a browser) use this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(thefile);
```